# extending Javascript object feature set

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am not much of a JavaScript expert and trying to figure out here how can I extend an existing object.

**HTML:**

```
<li data-brandtarget="Netherlands"><img src="images/netherlands.png" alt="Netherlands">Netherlands</li>
<li data-brandtarget="Netherlands"><img src="images/netherlands.png" alt="Netherlands">Netherlands</li>
```

**JS:**

```
MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet(
  // Brand Fetures
  new storeLocator.Feature('Aquafleur-YES', 'Aquafleur'),
  new storeLocator.Feature('Aquafarm-YES', 'Aquafarm'),  
  new storeLocator.Feature('Bm_Web-YES', 'Blue Marine'),
  // The below mentioned features I want to be added based on a loop
  //new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-Netherlands', 'Netherlands'),
  //new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-Great Britain', 'Great Britain'),
  //new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-France', 'France'),
  //new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-Germany', 'Germany')
);
```

I am trying to make the country features dynamic. So I am looping through all the lists and getting the attribute. Now while looping how can I extend and add new feature to the existing object? Below is **my approach.**

```
jQuery('.country-options li').each(function(){

    var countryName = jQuery(this).attr('data-brandtarget');

    MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet(
      // Country Features
      new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-'+ countryName, countryName)
    );    

});
```

I know it is wrong because I guess: I am creating the new object again and again with each loop which overwrites the existing object and thus only the last feature stays in the object.

So what is the right way to extend the features without overwriting the existing feature set here?

**I also tried:**
by removing the `new` and keeping it just `storeLocator.FeatureSet(...);` inside the loop but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/reference.html) I found, you can call `add()` on the existing `FeatureSet`:

```
MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet();

jQuery('.country-options li').each(function(){

  var countryName = jQuery(this).attr('data-brandtarget');

  MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_.add(
    new storeLocator.Feature('Naamlandnat-'+ countryName, countryName)
  );    

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.